# Can I open two or more files in vim at once?

Tags: vim

I have a file with the name **First.txt**, which I opened that by vim. Now I want to go another file which its name is  **Second.txt** .

1. How to open **Second.txt** while I do not close **First.txt**.
2. How to switch between them **First.txt** and **Second.txt** on the vim?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can open a different file in vim with the `:o` command, like so:

```
:o /file/To/Open
```

This closes your current file and opens `/file/To/Open`.

As of vim 7.0 you can use the *tabs* feature to open multiple files at once.  Use vim's `:tabnew` command to open a new tab:

```
:tabnew [filename]
```

Where `[filename]` is an optional file to open in the new tab.

To switch between tabs use any of the following commands:

- `:tabn` - switches to the next tab.
- `:tabp` - switches to the previous tab.
- `gt` - toggles through all tabs, from left to right.
- `gT` - similar to `gt` but in opposite direction.
- `:tabfirst` - switches to the first tab.
- `:tablast` - switches to the last tab.

You can also pass multiple files to vim and have it open them in different tabs like so:

```
vim -p file1 file2 etc
```

To close a tab, use the `:tabclose` command.

For more tab related info see [*Vim tips: using tabs*](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442422-vim-tips-using-tabs) on Linux.com.

Comment: or just `:tabe [filename]` instead of `:tabnew [filename]`

Comment: This is a really good answer. Better than what I found elsewhere.

Comment: also, you can switch between tabs (when open using `:tabnew <file>`) using Ctrl+Shift+Up or Down. (easier than enter :command).

Answer (score 0):

To open a file in a different subdirectory while in a common parent directory you could use:
:tabe ./src/[filename] or :tabnew ./src/[filename]

In my case I was in current directory lua-c, I had a /scripts subdirectory for *.lua scripts and a /src subdirectory for *.c source code. One file, in this scenario the *.lua file, was already open.

It's so simple in vi/vim to open and close files from the same directory that I put up with the minor inconvenience of only having one file open. When I started to use files in different folders, failing to remember their locations became very painful.

Comment: Who is a **Udemy instructor**, what is a **Lua class** and how is this important to your answer?

Comment: I removed a reference to the online education provider's programming class.